# Android 5 Lollipop SQLite Performance

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop

Testing on Nexus 5, ran the Lollipop update and afterwards my SQLite queries now take forever to execute I'd says 3x, 4x times longer than in Ice Cream Sandwich

Android 4 was shipping with 3.7 ver of SQLite, Android 5 now comes with improved 3.8 version which was supposed to introduce performance improvement of 50% (in theory at least).

However I'm not seeing this at all, SQLite performance seems horrid in Lollipop.

Testing side-by-side with an old Galaxy 3 running Ice Cream Sandwich my queries take 1-2 seconds, after the Lollipop upgrade queries started to take much longer 10-15 sec.

DB has proper indexes created.

And issue exists only in Lollipop.

Has anyone faced similar issues, and any advice on how to resolve?

Sample query & explain query output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 t.route_id, s.stop_name, s.stop_id, s.stop_lat, s.stop_lon, s.location_type 
FROM 
 stops s 
 INNER JOIN stop_times st ON s.stop_id=st.stop_id 
 INNER JOIN trips t ON t.trip_id=st.trip_id 
WHERE 
 s.lon > -111.84006 AND s.lon < -111.81482 AND 
 s.lat > 34.839073 AND s.lat < 34.86432 AND 
 service_id IN (SELECT service_id FROM calendar WHERE saturday='1')
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is to rewrite your queries and to add apprpriate indexes. Without the database schema and the queries themselves, nobody can help you.

Comment: I find your comment invalid. Re-writing SQL queries per Android version is not a valid solution. As stated above queries take 1-2 seconds outside of Lollipop. Issue is isolated to Android 5.0 only.

Comment: So you don't want your queries to take a few milliseconds on any version?

Comment: Milliseconds would be sweet :) but what's throwing me off is that it happens only on 5. I will update the post with a sample query.

Comment: ... and the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output.

Comment: What is the EXLPLAIN QUERY PLAN output with the other version? Is the DISTINCT really necessary? Did you run [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html)? Can't you ship your app with your own copy of SQLite that includes the [r-tree module](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to R-Tree, seems more elegant, reading up on it now. The EXPLAN QUERY PLAN output above is actually from a desktop SQLite browser. As you mention this I assume QUERY PLAN will differ by device/SQLite driver. I'm going to run it on both test devices and share output.

Comment: I've resolved the issue by optimizing the query. R-Tree seems like the correct solution for this, but I wanted to avoid complexity of adding SQLite module as this runs on a device. Furthermore I've traced the bottleneck to the cursor logic, my query itself now takes milliseconds. I feel you should add the R-Tree pointer as a solution as it is valid given the context of the original question.

Comment: Can you explain how you changed the cursor logic to get sqlite performance on Lollipop back to normal?

Comment: I ended up doing query analysis across multiple test devices, running EXPLAIN QUERY on multiple devices with different Android versions and adding some indexes to speed things up (don't over do it). This took time as it seems that SQLite query execution is different on other Android versions as they use different versions of SQLite engine - so testing required.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite 3.8 introduced the [Next Generation Query Planner](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html). It may make different choices, but is *supposed* to be better.

(I'm assuming here that the query plans for your query differ in a significant way between sqlite versions. You've only posted one of them.)

Allow me to quote an excerpt from the [docs on the new planner](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html#hazards), "Hazards of upgrading to NGQP":

> But as with any query planner change, upgrading to the NGQP does carry a small risk of introducing performance regressions. The problem here is not that the NGQP is incorrect or buggy or inferior to the legacy query planner. Given reliable information about the selectivity of indices, the NGQP should always pick a plan that is as good or better than before. The problem is that some applications may be using low-quality and low-selectivity indices without having run ANALYZE. The older query planners look at many fewer possible implementations for each query and so they may have stumbled over a good plan by stupid luck. The NGQP, on the other hand, looks at many more query plan possibilities, and it may choose a different query plan that works better in theory, assuming good indices, but which gives a performance regression in practice, because of the shape of the data.

Summarized:

- The new planner is more dependent on correct statistics (to know which strategy will exclude the most rows the fastest)
- Without them, it may make bad choices (choosing to use the wrong, or even *no* index)
- You should update your table statistics with ANALYZE (or manually insert statistics from the typical/worst-case situation into the statistics tables)

So, see if running ANALYZE helps your query performance. Compare the query plan and performance before and after on both sqlite versions (and it'd be cool if you posted all four situations for others to see the difference).

Comment: In my situation with full text search (FTS3), ANALYZE improves performance in 50 times. Thank you.